# Sqlalchemy filter on object

Tags: python, filter, orm, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

I have a script that will test some conditions of objects in a SQLAlachemy ORM driven database. This will all be dynamic and that's given me some problems.

I want to query the minimum amount of objects for all tests, therefor all tests have a default filtering. If I were to test 2 tests, both filters will be applied to the query so I get the minimal amount of objects.

```
class Employee(Base):
    name = Column(String ...)
    account = Column(Account ...)
    coworkers = relationship(Employee_coworker, use_list=True ...)
    ...
```

So when I get all objects, I want to use my 2 filters

```
filter_1 = Employee.account != None
filter_2 = Employee.coworkers.any()
for e in session.query(Employee).filter(or_(filter_1, filter_2)).all():
    # IF e is here because of filter_1: 
    # Do something
    # IF e is here because of filter_2:
    # Do this thing
...
```

**Is it possible to test an object by the same way a query gets filtered?**

Comment: can't you just check the `account` and `coworker` members respectively for the same condition you filtered them with?

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible, without rewriting the condition again (wich I try to avoid)..

Comment: In that case, if I understand you correctly, the answer is no. The database does not tell you why it returned the records it did. As far as I'm aware, SQLAlchemy doesn't do any analysis on that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly ask the database to tell you what matched:

```
filter1 = ...
filter2 = ...
filters = [filter1, filter2, ...]
query = session.query(Employee, *filters).filter(or_(*filters))
for employee, filter1_applied, filter2_applied, ... in query:
    ...
```